# Low gravity planet, insect niche design

Tags: creature-design, gravity, anatomy

I am trying to think of alternatives to arthropods as the small critters for the planets I am designing but I am unsure how gravity will affect their design.

These creatures will fill the roles that insects play in the ecosystem from breaking down dead life-forms to pollinating on the planets with flowering plants, they will stick to the sizes of modern day insects from microscopic to a few inches long for the largest.

How would lower gravity (60-80%G) affect the body plan and anatomy of small creatures that fill the insect niche?

Comment: This reads as a request to brainstorm, which is considered a poor fit for this forum

Comment: It seems contingent on them being able to fly - at least the pollination part. Breaking down corpses is a different niche, so this seems very broad at present, probably accounting for the downvotes. You can ask a series of questions in their own threads, as long as each is specific enough, perhaps describe in detail a niche and the set of requirements - as a start.

Comment: So people can ask how life would be different at lower g (happy Alexp) but asking about a specific sized creature is somehow a ridiculous question.

Comment: The thing is, there are already birds that pollinate flowers (hummingbird), birds that deal with corpses (vultures, corvids) - you would need to explain why you'd dismissed these options and be much more specific about your requirements. We don't engage in personal criticism so much as try to help people focus their ideas into something useful for their world.

Comment: As Willk said, gravity is a minor consideration for such small creatures. That's why it looks like brainstorming @GaultDrakkor. But the best answer is likely just "not much to expect from this change, so knowing this only you're not really adding any constraints to your creatures". There's not much discussion here. It looks quite broad though.

Answer (score 3):

**For crawlers, there is already a huge variety of body plans on Earth.**

[image: crawlers]

All of these creatures inhabit the niche you envision for your world. They have very different body plans.  And you can find more - there are other animal body plans which only occur in marine creatures but which might have given rise to terrestrial animal lineages.  I think gravity is a minor consideratiion for such small creatures.

---

**Flyers are probably influenced for my atmospheric pressure than gravity**.

As atmospheric pressure and gas density increases, it gets more like a fluid.  It is easier to support the weight of an organism with something more dense it can push against.  If you want a world of big fliers you could have a high atmospheric pressure / low gravity world and let them swim thru your skies.

Comment: When I said body plan I didnt mean number limbs, i was more thinking about the exoskeleton, molluscs do fill the same your right but they can fill all as they are so slow.

Comment: @SimonDiamond well, snails maybe but the squids might have an issue with "slow".  Also there is a crustacean up there.  I only put one worm (the leech) but there are 2 other phyla of worms you could draw from.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that lower gravity could affect the body plan and anatomy of small creatures that fill the insect niche.

One way is that it could affect the way they move. In lower gravity, creatures would likely be able to jump higher and farther than they could in higher gravity. This could change the way their legs are shaped and how they move them.

Another way that lower gravity could affect these creatures is by changing the way their wings work. In lower gravity, wings would likely be much less efficient at flying than they are in higher gravity. This could mean that creatures with wings might have to find other ways to get around, such as gliding or jumping.

Finally, lower gravity could also affect the way these creatures reproduce. In lower gravity, it would be easier for eggs and sperm to travel through the air, which could make it easier for creatures to reproduce without having to find a mate. This could lead to more creatures being born without parents, or it could lead to creatures having multiple parents.